# Existence and Uniqueness Theorem in a situation where the y-derivative is unbounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to Differential Equations and am stuck at the following:

Find two different solutions to the initial value problem
$$y'=x^2~(y-1)^{1/3}~,\qquad y(0)=1$$
and explain why there is no contradiction with the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

I managed two find the two solutions with relative ease:

$$y_1=1+\frac{2\sqrt2}{27}x^{\frac{9}{2}}~~,\qquad ~~ y_2=1-\frac{2\sqrt2}{27}x^{\frac{9}{2}}$$
However, I am stuck at the second part of the question. I noticed that the derivatives according to $y$ at $x=0$ are undefined, but am not sure whether that is a valid argument to say that the regular conditions for the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem are not met.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,1)}{y-1}=x^{2}(y-1)^{\frac{-2}{3}}$, $y \ne 1$ which is unbounded in any rectangle $|x| \le a$, $|y-1| \le b$, where a and b are finite non negative real numbers. So, Lipschitz condition is not satisfied.